# Azure PushNotification on Xamarin.iOS not working

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started) to implement Push Notification for iOS and it is not working.
I implemented the same code that are available in the documentation and nothing else.
The test performed was the one sent by the azure itself.
For Android everything is working.

I was looking for this error and found about removing the spaces and "<" / ">", making this change was also not effective.
I also checked and rechecked the connectionString and hubpath.

When I send the test via azure, it appears that it was sent to a device but nothing appears, and I opened that application on only one device.

Does anyone know anything about it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that using certificates is the older method, personally I find using the APNS keys to be a lot easier, and less prone to issues with certificate build problems.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I will try with keys. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving push notifications while the app is in sandbox/debug mode will not work. If you deploy the app in releasemode you will be able to receive the messages.

Comment: I'm trying making the deploy.